# How to search a string and extract another string pattern from a text file using windows batch script

Tags: windows, script, batch-file

Consider out.txt file have the following format

```
Display Variable;

ID    NAME       value
===*==========*================
201  Variavle     07Dec2014

Display Variable12;

ID    NAME          value
===*==========*================
201  Variavle12     08Dec2014

Display Variable123;

ID    NAME       value
===*==========*================
201  Variavle123     09Dec2014
```

Test.bat

In Batch file we need search for for the Variable, Variable12 and Variable123, return each variable value to batch files named the same as the variables.

```
SET Variavle=09Dec2014
SET Variavle12=08Dec2014
SET Variavle123=09Dec2014
```

Please help me to get it done.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. SuperUser is not a "please write me a script" kind of site, but we do help troubleshooting problems with scripts. What have you tried so far and where are things not working as they should?

Comment: able to search the string "Variable     " after the pattern cnt ale to extract the value.

Comment: Same comments as @LPChip. Do research, start a script, then ask more specific questions. As a starting point, for searching files and setting variables in batch files see http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: Can you clarify for us (me), are the batch files are named "Variavle.bat", "Variavle12.bat", etc., or "09Dec2014.bat", "08Dec2014.bat", etc.? What have you tried so far, where exactly are you getting suck?

Comment: I have main batch file "main.bat"-> i try to search strings like Variavle, Variavle12, Variavle123 in "log.txt" file. If any of the variable found then return the variable value like Variavle=07Dec2014, Variavle12=08Dec2014, Variavle123=09Dec2014 in the same batch file as a same variable and value

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2-3" %%a in ('
        findstr /b /r /c:"[0-9]" "log.txt"
    ') do set "%%a=%%b"

    set Variav
```

`for /f` is used to

1. Execute a `findstr` command over the `log.txt` file, searching the lines that start with a number
2. Tokenize the lines using spaces or tabs as delimiters, and retrieving the second and third tokens in the line into the replaceable parameters `%%a` (the starting one indicated in the command) and `%%b` (the alphabetically next one)

For each line found, the `do` clause is executed and the variable defined.

The final `set Variav` is only included to output to console the defined variables.